# Generating a static page from a script

Tags: scripts

I use a script to generate the ranking page http://joereddington.com/ranking.html from a script.  Here's a relevant bit of the script:

```
cat $DIR/start.html > $DESTINATION_PAGE
grep -o "<img.*Global rank.*" * | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed 's/\(^.*\):\(.*\)/<\/td><td><a href=\"http:\/\/\1\">\1<\/a><\/td><td> \2 <\/td><td><\/td><\/tr>/' > thelist.txt
cat thelist.txt | sort -n -k 3 | head -n 60 > thelist2.txt
cat thelist2.txt | nl | sed 's/^/<tr><td>/g' >> $DESTINATION_PAGE
echo "</table><br> Ranking last updated at: " >> $DESTINATION_PAGE
date >> $DESTINATION_PAGE
cat $DIR/end.html >> $DESTINATION_PAGE
```

You can view the full script at [this](https://github.com/joereddington/ranking/blob/master/create_ranking.sh) github project. What I'm doing to generate this page is that I'm taking a static html version of the normal pages on my blog (split into two parts) and just squashing the html in with the generated table to create something that 'looks' reasonable.  This clearly isn't the best way of putting regularly changing text into a wordpress installation. So what *is* the best way of putting regularly changing text into a WordPress install?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how one would define "best", but a possible approach would be to make your rankings page an actual page within WordPress, then add either a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) or a [filter on `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) to populate/fetch a [transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) from the database. You could alternately save it in an [option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) or as [post meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and cron a script to update the option/meta periodically. [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) may be of interest to you as well.